# Python3 isdigit

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with isdigit.  I have added extra lines to see where my code is getting but I cannot get the If statements to work so that fnum and snum are turned into integers.  The whole idea is that I was having problems with the equation line in my script being returned right, so this will catch to make sure both numbers in the equation can be integers before being turned into integers and possibly crashing the script.  I have tried with the answers as 'True' and also 'true' to make sure it wasnt a capitalization issue.  I printed both lines out before the if statements to see that the isdigit line is written correctly, both return True although I am not getting inside of the if statement.  Here is my code below:

```
equation = "1+2"
isdig = 0
fnum=0
snum=0
print (equation)
firstnum = equation[0]
secondnum = equation[2]
print (firstnum)
print (secondnum)
print (firstnum.isdigit())
print(secondnum.isdigit())
if firstnum.isdigit() == "True":
    print ('yes')
    fnum=int(firstnum)
    isdig = isdig + 1

if secondnum.isdigit() == "True":
    print ('yes')
    snum=int(secondnum)
    isdig = isdig + 1

sign = equation[1]
print (sign)

if sign == '-' or sign == '+':
    if sign == '-':
        answer = fnum - snum
    if sign =="+":
        print ("addition")
        answer = fnum + snum
    isdig = isdig + 1

print (answer)
print (isdig)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is with equality you should use `True` of type `bool` instead of `"True"` of type `str`.